# How do I solve the FileNotFound error in Python3 while writing code on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

I have tried downloading the file multiple times and also changed its location. But still, I am getting the same error.
The code I had written was:

```
import pandas as pd
data_set=pd.read_csv('F:\\Startups.csv')
```

The error I am getting is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'F:\\Startups.csv' does not exist: b'F:\\Startups.csv'
```

Comment: Is the file available in that folder?

Comment: Is the Startups.csv exist? And Did you check the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to put the data and the notebook in the same folder and just call `data_set = pd.read_csv('Startups.csv')`.

However if you want to keep the data and the code in an organized way, you can create a folder like below and call `data_set = pd.read_csv('Data\Startups.csv')`

[image]